# Validate the text containing opening and closing tags

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How to Validate text in C#, and the text contains opening tag and closing tag and  is not related to html or xml or any other script?

Comment: You should read this first: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: loop the char in the string one by one until you meet the char "<". Then capture the text within before next ">". By this you can capture can validate the tag

Comment: What do you mean by 'text'? You mean something simple like checking validation of an Email, Password or something? Then you can use [Regular Expressions (RegEx)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.1). Otherwise you should look for [Domain Specific Languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language).

Comment: For example

<abc>
this is a sample text
</abc>
<def>
this is a sample text in another tag
</def>
<efg>
this is a sample text in some other tag
</efg>

Comment: @sairamch Your example is XML language. But in your question you said it is not related to XML.

Comment: In your example and in that case, you can use [XMLDocument API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: @0xaryan But in my text has not root tag and attributes. Only tags in order.

Comment: @sairamch You are right. But you still can add a fake root to it and then pass it to XMLDocument for checking then check validity.

Comment: @sairamch something like this: `$"<root>{toBeChecked}</root>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can **"Validate the text containing opening and closing tags"**

```
string mystring="<html><body><p>Hello World</p></body></html>";
bool iscontainTags=mystring.Contains("<") || mystring.Contains(">")?true:false;
```

> iscontainTags=true

Comment: Hi @Taha Thanx for your comment but we don't know even tags to validate in the text.